# PCIe Bus Error: Severity=corrected type=Physical Layer ID=00e5(Receiver ID)- How to fix this error on Linux Mint?

Tags: dual-boot

Recently, I had installed Ubuntu 19.04 alongside Windows 10. For a couple of days, it was loading fine and then the PCIe Bus error as mentioned in the title started showing up and it was sending infinite messages. I tried several fixes but none of them worked out. Then I tried installed Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS but started facing the same error after a couple of days. I then installed Linux Mint alongside Windows 10, but the same error comes up.

Hardware Details:

```
Asus X541U
Ram:4+4GB
Hard disk: 500 GB(250 for windows 10 & 215 GB for Ubuntu)
64-bit Architecture
OS used: Windows 10 Single Language and Linux Ubuntu 19.04, 18.4.2 LTS and  Mint 19.2 Cinnamon
```

I have added the screenshot of the error. I am facing this error only on this system. On my other system, dual booting is working very well. Why is this happening?

Comment: I forget to add one thing. I told that after installation of Ubuntu, they are running fine for a couple of days before the PCIe error starts to appear. But however, during those days, the kernel log files are as heavy as 1 GB and more and suddenly, I ran out of root space(note that I have kept 120gb for root alone).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the same Asus Laptop Model and I too faced the same error on Ubuntu and not with Mint as I am using only Ubuntu alongside Windows 10. I tried the following fix which actually worked for me.

### Steps to fix this issue:

1. Turn on the system.
2. On the Grub menu, Press e while the highlighter is on ubuntu(in your
   case, Linux Mint).
3. Now, we have to edit the line. Keep the cursor or blinker before the
   the term "**quiet splash**" and type `pcie_aspm=off` and then press **CTRL + X**
   to save and continue booting. I added the image below kindly refer to the image.

[image]

For me, Ubuntu started loading up after this and finally,

- I have to update my grub so that the above command will be included
  every time when the system loads.
- Assuming the system loaded normally, let us update the grub. Open the
  terminal and run the command `sudo update-grub`. this command will
  update the grub with the above-made changes.

The above fix worked for me and I hope it works for you as well.

Comment: The above method did work for me. However, on the Grub Menu Edit line, the interface was totally different with Linux Mint and I managed to find that quiet splash and added the term and to my surprise, Mint was loading properly. Thank you for the fix.